# Android - Passing value from ListFragment to another ListFragment

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I have a listview containing Category of items. When I press a category title on the list, it will display another listview containing items inside the chosen Category.

I'm doing this by using ListFragment. Do I have to start a new activity and pass the Category ID together in the intent?

Here's my `ListFragment` for Category:

```
public class CategoryFragment extends ListFragment implements
        OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        // what to do here 
    }
}
```

What do I add in the `onItemClick` to go to the Items List? Do I need to use another ListFragment or just use regular ListActivity?

How do I retrieve Category ID from the parsed JSON and pass it to the List item?

EDIT: I parsed the JSON using Volley. I'm thinking of creating an invisible TextView in the layout for the category ID so I can pull it from there. Is that possible?

Comment: use interface as a callback to the activtiy. then communicate values to another fragment.  fragment to fragment communication is done through the activity.

Comment: I'll take a look on that. Please read my updated question.

Comment: you could use a exapandalbe listview

Comment: The problem with expandable listview is the item list is too long. So it's an anti-pattern. I'd use a normal listview though so I can implement load more button.

Comment: as i said use interface as a callback to the activity then communicate to other fragment or start a new listactivity an pass values using intents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let your `FragmentActivity` implement an interface that has a `categorySelected(int categoryId)` method.

Inside CategoryOverviewFragment you call this when a category is selected:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    ((CategorySelectedListener)getActivity()).categorySelected(i);
}
```

Then in the activity you implement `categorySelected` and replace the overview fragment with `CategoryFragment`.

When you create you `CategoryFragment` set the cateogry ID as argument. It's best to use the [newInstance pattern](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/using-newinstance-to-instantiate.html) to `setArguments()`.

To replace the category overview list fragment with the category details fragment use the [`FragmentManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) to [`beginTransaction()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#beginTransaction%28%29) and then [`replace()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment%29).

Assuming the category overview fragment is added dynamically and not in XML use code like this:

```
CategoryFragment newFragment = CategoryFragment.newInstance(categoryIdSelected);
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

transaction.commit();
```

If the category list fragment is added in XML you need to remove that change it to a `FrameLayout` and add the fragment dynamically in the code.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Interface`, it's the "official" way to pass values to `Fragment`.
Take a look at this documentation here :

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity

So what you need to do :

FragmentA --> Activity --> FragmentB

An invisible `TextView` is definitely not the correct solution...

**EDIT A more detailed solution :**

You define an interface (in a separate file or in your FragmentA class) :

```
public interface MyFragmentListener {
    public void onFragmentItemSelected(String url);
}
```

in your FragmentA class :

```
MyFragmentListener myListener;

public void setMyFragmentListener(MyFragmentListener listener) {
    myListener = listener;
}

// here I used the onClick method but you can call the listener whereever you like.
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (myListener != null) {
        myListener.onFragmentItemSelected(url);
    }
}
```

Declaration your FragmentB class :

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment implements MyFragmentListener {


    public void onFragmentItemSelected(String url) {
        // do what you want to do
    }


}
```

in your Activity :

```
// you tell your fragmentA that his listener is the FragmentB. And because you implemented the listener in FragmentB, everything is allright;
fragmentA.setMyFragmentListener(fragmentB));
```

Comment: I still can't get my head around this. How do I access the `category_id` and pass it to an interface? I did the interface part and all is working well except, I can't retrieve a `category_id` from **fragment A** when an item was pressed. I need the id in **fragment B** as a parameter for JSON url. Hm.

Comment: can u tell what is `fragmentB` in `fragmentA.setMyFragmentListener(fragmentB));`

Answer (score 1):

Use this ........

```
      list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem

            int new_position = position;
            String disp = dataList.get(new_position).get("displaytext");
            String msg = dataList.get(new_position).get("message");
            String pht = dataList.get(new_position).get("photo");
            String mt = dataList.get(new_position).get("messagetime");
            String fpht = dataList.get(new_position).get("feedphoto");
            String prdctprice = dataList.get(new_position).get(
                    "productprice");
            String pid = dataList.get(new_position).get("productid");
            String cmntcount = dataList.get(new_position).get(
                    "commentcount");
            String storeid = dataList.get(new_position).get("storeid");

            addfragment(new FeedChat(c, disp, msg, pht, mt, fpht,
                    prdctprice, pid, storeid, cmntcount), true,
                    FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Communication Between Two `Fragment` is Done Via `Activity` using `Interface`

`Fragment` A-------------------------->`Activity`-------------------->`Fragment` B

(defines `Interface`)               (implements `interface`)        ( pass to `Fragment` B)

[Doc reference is Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity)