# Android Fragment Item on click event change the detail fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

[image]

I'm new to android tablet application development. I'm developing tablet application and I want to change the details fragment view according to the `onclick` event of the list fragment item.

on my approach, list fragment item click changes the details fragment data.

appreciate any help

Comment: Take a look at my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21040664/android-passing-value-from-listfragment-to-another-listfragment/21040778#21040778

Comment: You can generate a skeleton activity that has the necessary Master/Detail plumbing automatically in Eclipse. Create a new Android Application using the wizard and choose to create an a Master/Detail flow activity.