# How to send data from ListFragment to Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

So my ListFragment is Tab2 and it looks something like this.

```
public class Tab2 extends ListFragment {

public interface MyFragmentListener {
    public void onFragmentItemSelected(String CheckSwitch);
}
static MyFragmentListener myListener;

public static void setMyFragmentListener(MyFragmentListener listener) {
    myListener = listener;
}
```

on some condition

```
if (TempTweet < CheckingTemp) 
{
    myListener.onFragmentItemSelected("TurnOn");
}
```

on Tab1

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment implements Tab2.MyFragmentListener {

@Override
public void onFragmentItemSelected(String CheckSwitch) {
    if(CheckSwitch.equals("TurnOn"))
    {
        //Some Actions
    }
}
```

on MainActivity

```
Tab2.setMyFragmentListener(Tab1);
```

This answer has been taken from [Passing value from ListFragment to another ListFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21040778/3796048) now i am very new to Java and android so i am not sure it always says "Expression Expected"

Comment: Please check https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: @abhishesh I read it but unable to understand anything. May be I am new to Java and working on android is making it more difficult for me to understand

Comment: @abhishesh Do u mean to say that we dont need to "tell your Tab2 that his listener is the Tab1." in the activity

Comment: what error you are facing? can you paste the logs here

Comment: No such error @Farhan just red line over Tab1 and on mouse over it says Expression expected

Answer (score 1):

You can make global static variable so that you can use it wherever you want.